# Are power contracts traded on any stock market?

Tags: options, equities, derivatives

Are power contracts traded on any stock markets ? What about OTC markets ?  I ask about the derivatives where payoff is some exponential function of difference between strike and spot price.

Comment: Power contracts were always the domain of the theoreticians.  I never saw one go through our exotics desk (though our software would have supported it, because it was so darn easy to put in the library).

Answer (score 1):

Stock markets? Not that I know of.  I would say ICE and NYMEX have OTC power contracts but I believe they have pretty big margins and account minimums for that kind of contract.  Just at looking at today's settlements I see very little traded on Clearport.

Comment: Qbik is thinking about options as described [here](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/PricingPowerOptionsInTheBlackScholesModel/). The power refers to a power function, not electricity.

Answer (score 0):

Levered ETFs have the behavior similar to power contracts, but there aren't any listed options. Some banks should be able to sell you OTC contracts, although I doubt you can do any arbitrage like trade if you are hoping to do - the bid and ask will kill you!

Answer (score 0):

CME is another derivatives market that trades power markets

Comment: Qbik is thinking about "power options" as described here https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/PricingPowerOptionsInTheBlackScholesModel/ , options where $S$ is raised to a power (i.e. an exponent) in calculating the payoff, not about contracts on electrical power.

Comment: By default, I thought of electricity options because I'm the energy industry. So my answer is irrelevant